# Not sure how to programmatically filter by taxonomy metadata in my custom search webpart

Tags: sharepoint, search, metadata, sharepoint-2010, taxonomy

I have pages in a pages library on a publishing site which have a managed metadata (taxonomy) field in their content type. I want my custom search webpart to read the taxonomy set on its parent page (I can do this fine) and then query against a specific scope using only the selected tags of the parent page as the filter (no keyword necessary).

I have tried to set FixedQuery = “owstaxIdMetadataAllTagsInfo=#0[TERM GUID]” of my CoreResultWebPart with no success... I actually gave up after I was getting 0 results and am now trying to just perform a FullTextSqlQuery.

Unfortunately it seems that even though pages with the managed metadata field are successfully being indexed, the managed property owstaxIdMetadataAllTagsInfo has no data in the results! I went ahead and made the property searchable/queryable and the property value is null.

Can you anyone confirm that I should be getting values from that managed property when there is indeed a managed metadata field on the page that is populated with data?

Note: I have tried to make my own managed property based on the managed metadata field in my site's content type -- same results.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think - owstaxIdMetadataAllTagsInfo  returns anything. I tried adding it to my result web part's Diaplay properties > fetched properties and got a property not recognized...related error.
So I created a separate metadata property for 'enterprise keywords' i.e. 'TaxKeyword. You need to ensure that you check the checkbox - 'Reduce storage requirements for text properties by using a hash for comparison' otherwise no results will be returned for that peroperty is you use LIKE predicate with fulltextsql.